# serialization of checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-serialization

Hi i have a couple of checkboxes, how do i go about serialize them?

I have a class that declares other variables to be serialized:

```
public class FormSaving
        {
            public string Majorversion
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string Minorversion
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public int Buildstartingmail
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
```

where my Buildstartingmail is to be assigned to the BuildstartingmailcheckBox.

how should i do it?

i was thinking of using something like

```
abc.Buildstartingmail = BuildstartingmailcheckBox.SelectedIndex
```

but there is no such option as "SelectedIndex"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty solutions :

1. You can save checkbox's index in `Conrol` collection
2. You can store checkboxes in dictinary and save keys
3. You can save checkbox's name
4. You can use `Tag` property of checkbox to store unique id and then save that id